# Pythonic way to split string then split again on result?

Tags: python, split, idioms

Is there a more pythonic way to do this

```
def parse_address(hostname, addresses):
    netmask=''
    for address in addresses:
        if hostname in address:
            _hostname, _netmask = address.strip().split('/')
            hostname = _hostname.split()[-1]
            netmask = '/' + _netmask.split()[0]
            break

    return netmask
```

#### Test case

If you do TDD

```
def test_parse_netmask(self):
        hostname = '127.0.0.1'

        stdout = [
            "1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
            "3: wlp4s0    inet 192.168.2.133/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic wlp4s0\       valid_lft 58984sec preferred_lft 58984sec",
            "4: docker0    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
            "5: br-a49026d1a341    inet 172.18.0.1/16 scope global br-a49026d1a341\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
            "6: br-d26f2005f732    inet 172.19.0.1/16 scope global br-d26f2005f732\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
        ]

        netmask = scanner.parse_address(hostname, stdout)

        self.assertEqual(netmask, '/8')
```

Comment: So you basically only want the number behind your hostname?

Comment: haha yeah, I was fetching the hostname early-on

Comment: No, the question you really want to ask yourself is, "How do I make the source input machine parsable?"

Comment: @CivFan This is the result of a [unix command on a remote device](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/blob/bf880bd46b3151864e3c444b40246aabbe305a13/daemon/api/network_tools.py#L61) it's the best structured format I can get

Comment: If you have control of the remote code, and can use the `psutil` module, take a look at [`psutil.net_if_addrs()`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.net_if_addrs).

Comment: There is already remote devices deployed and we need backward-compatible with them, so for now, it's through SSH, otherwise might need to write some Ansible role to do it. But that's probably for another sprint.
@CivFan Thanks for the tip anyway, might serve another day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def x(hostname,addresses):
    import re 
    for address in addresses:
        result = re.search(hostname+r"/\d", address)
        if result:
            return result.group(0).split(hostname)[1]
```

Don't know if it's more 'Pythonic' but I would do it this way. It's readable to others, yet it's short enough to not drag on the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
hostname = '127.0.0.1'
stdout = [
            "1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
            "3: wlp4s0    inet 192.168.2.133/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic wlp4s0\       valid_lft 58984sec preferred_lft 58984sec",
            "4: docker0    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
            "5: br-a49026d1a341    inet 172.18.0.1/16 scope global br-a49026d1a341\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
            "6: br-d26f2005f732    inet 172.19.0.1/16 scope global br-d26f2005f732\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever",
        ]

print [item.split('/')[-1] for item in re.findall(r'(?:\d+\.){3}\d+\/\d+',''.join(stdout)) if hostname  in item]

['8']
```

Comment: I suggest using re.compile() before the loop. If nothing else it will make it more readable to have some of that code outside of the comprehension part

Comment: Regex are a powerful tool, but I think you're overdoing it and your code is not explicit at all. A more "readable" solution will be `re.findall('\d/(?P<netmask>\d+)', line)`

Answer (score -1):

Would you be able to base it on code like this?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parseResult = urlparse('http://www.fake.ca/185')
print ( parseResult )
```

parseResult is a structure with elements that are revealed in the output of the print statement.

ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.fake.ca', path='/185', params='', query='', fragment='')